# Converting a tail-recursive merge function in Scala to a HOF-based one

Tags: algorithm, scala, functional-programming

This is the typical tail-recursive merge function in Scala (that'll use as an example, but I'm actually looking for a general answer for converting these kind of functions):

```
  def merge(A: List[Int], B: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    @tailrec def merge(A: List[Int], B: List[Int], acc: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
      (A, B) match {
        case (Nil, Nil) => acc.reverse
        case (Nil, h::t) => merge(Nil, t, h::acc)
        case (h::t, Nil) => merge(t, Nil, h::acc)
        case (a::ha, b::hb) =>
          if (a < b) merge(ha, b::hb, a::acc)
          else merge(a::ha, hb, b::acc)
      }
    }
    merge(A, B, Nil)
  }
```

I was wondering if by using standard HOFs from the Scala collections it would be possible to avoid having to implement a recursive function.

It seems like I would always have to start by something like `(A zip B)` but after that I don't really know what path to follow. Could someone help? Is this just a worthless idea to follow?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe folding the resulting collection after using `zipAll` with default or `None` values?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the "general answer" part. How far are we generalizing? To other sort algorithms? Or tail recursive functions in general? It's hard to tell what exactly is the purpose here... I mean, you can always just do `(a ++ b).sorted`, but I doubt you want to implement merge sort by using another built-in sort. As far as zipping goes, you can't really zip, because it might be that first n elements of `a` should come before anything in `b`, so zipping in pairs is useless. Think e.g. `[1, 2, 3, 5]` and `[4, 6, 7, 8]`... zipping (1, 4), (2, 6) etc is not gonna get you far.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you are trying to replace this code by a kind of structural recursion:

```
val merged = someNewDataStructure(A, B).fold(someFunction)
```

The problem is that in the original tail-recursive call depends on a values of the list.

Imagine the data structure that meets your requirements.
Then the way you traverse it depends on the values you store there. 
Even if it's possible it is very unnatural.